# What should I do when other reviewers reject a valid edit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, rejected-edits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6709231 was a good edit whose (not necessarily obvious) purpose was explained very well in its edit comment. Other reviewers, however, rejected it, claiming it did nothing to improve the post. It seems wrong to just go and make that edit myself, but on the other hand, it seems that *someone* should.

Comment: I'd say make the edit itself but also fix the post in ways needed. In this case that means you could change the spacing to fit better and fix a couple very minor English errors

Comment: I agreed that this was an useful edit. I have [done the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5670190/5) bypassing the queue.

Comment: Normally I would blame this on robo-reviewers, in which case flagging a post of the robo-reviewer with mod>custom>link to review item, explicit message that this is not about the post itself, and that you believe they are roboreviewing is appropriate. In this case I am not sure that it is roboreviewing, even though they should have payed more attention.

Comment: Wow, I have never seen a robo-reviewed **reject** before.

Comment: You'll just have to accept the fact that you'll _always_ come across either terrible edits and/or terrible reviewers and trying to correct it is generally a losing battle.

Answer (score 30):

Frankly, the fact that you're thinking about this enough to daintily squirm over these meta-level concerns of *ooh, it seems wrong to let my judgement override others* already tells me that you're far more conscientious than the people whose disagreement you feel bound to respect. The suggested edit review queue is frequently policed by button-mashing morons.

If you care enough to go to the effort of following up on what you consider an unusual but clearly good suggestion to ensure it gets accepted, I already trust your individual judgement over a collective of five reviewers. The system of requiring up to three votes to perform an action that any of the voters could've performed individually is strange anyway; remember that had you wanted to approve, but noticed a one-character typo the editor hadn't fixed and gone for the "Approve and Edit" button, you would have single-handedly overruled all the other voters and never even considered that there might be anything improper about it. If that wouldn't trouble you, why should this? People who spend more time, thought and care overriding others is, as far as I'm concerned, the system *working*.

When you do manually implement a rejected suggestion like this, I think it's nice to credit the author of the original suggestion and link to their suggestion from the edit message. In cases where I've [done](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18948086/revisions) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8798981/revisions) [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25454884/revisions), my edit summaries have looked like:

> Remove inappropriate tag as per (IMO wrongly rejected) suggested edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2979992

---

> Fix variable name typo as per wrongly-rejected suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3575122

---

> Implement https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5608992, which was rejected for no good reason I can see. This edit provides information posted by the asker in a comment on the editors answer, and is crucial to understanding the question, at least for me

Comment: It's kind of sad when you think about it. Reviewers are supposed to be this prudent *by default*. I've always maintained that review is something only a specific group of people are qualified to do, not just anyone with a certain rep milestone (i.e. pretty much anyone with more than a few dozen answers), but clearly SE values quantity over quality in this regard.

Comment: And then you have folks who are lost as to what to do when asked to "review" their declined flags - they're so accustomed to button-mashing that they associate the word "review" with exactly that, regardless of context.

Comment: @BoltClock: Shrug.  It's not always totally clear why a flag was declined.  The "flag" dialogue box doesn't tell you whether your action will put the post into a moderator queue or into a three-stooges queue or exactly how stringent the standard for "spam/offensive" is.  Or, for that matter, what exactly it is that moderators do.

Answer (score 11):

I think you should definitely make the edit yourself. If you are knowledgeable about this particular subject and have 2000+ rep so you edits aren't reviewed, than it seems like you are exactly the sort of person who should do this.

As to the original rejection I would have probably rejected this as well. In general I would be suspicious of it as it is changing a URL in a question.  The edit message

> linking to a static line on a changing site is a bad idea

is only clear if you already understand the problem. Given that several reputable folks here on Meta like it, I agree it is useful. But the edit message would have worked better if was something like

"OP attempted to link to a specific part of a website, but the URL needs to be changed to accomplish this".

I think in general if an edit is to code or URL's reviewers should be very wary in approving (why not just add a comment) and editors need to make a comment that will be clear to folks who aren't experts in the topic.

Personally I skip a lot of things in the edit queues, but the reviews are not restricted by expertise so the clearer the edit comment the better.

Comment: I'd say the message "linking to a static line on a changing site is a bad idea" is only clear if you understand GitHub. I'm not familiar with Node.js, but I am familiar with GitHub, and I definitely would have approved that edit if I were reviewing it.

Comment: I think your alternative edit comment is less clear than the original comment. "specific part of a website" isn't a good way of saying "a specific line in a code file", and you don't mention that the changing file is the problem.

Comment: Random goofballs proooobably shouldn't be rejecting or accepting edits that they don't understand.  It's still on the people who hit "reject" even if the edit summary can't bring you from obliviousness to understanding.  (And yeah, I would also have been one of those goofballs had I come across this, just because the review queue has trained me into thinking that almost all edits like this are garbage.  But that would be my fault, not the editor's.)

Answer (score 3):

Let's dissect the situation, what you've got is:

1. A question that can be improved. Even more, you have the power to improve it without much effort, since someone else already provided an improvement.
2. You know some users who made a questionable decision while reviewing.

For 1) the answer seems clear, make the edit yourself. If you *really* feel that bad for taking someone else's improvement, you could add a comment to credit the user.

For 2) there is no way you can contact those users. It seems futile to add a comment telling them the edit was wrong, I don't think it's very likely they will revisit the question.

Comment: Yes, I just didn't feel entirely comfortable letting my judgement override others, even when confident that it was, in fact, the correct one.

Comment: "Re-visit"? It's quite likely they never visited that question in the first place!

Comment: Yeah I guess I would think probably think a tiny bit more about the edit than usual, to check if my judgment could be off.

Comment: @Deduplicator I meant that they won't see the question again (after seeing it in the review process).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could write a comment below the question basically suggesting the edit to the OP. Explain to him that in order for the question to have better future value, he should link to a fixed "blob" version instead of the head/master, which is ever-changing. This seems a little more polite and would provide education to the OP on such matters as well. That's basically the reason why in Wikipedia (and academic works) citations of URLs usually have a "retrieved on" date mentioned.

I honestly ran into something rather similar recently, where a question (from 2012) contained a link to blog that had been updated in 2014 rendering the question moot/trivial. But this wasn't immediately obvious from the SO question-text... The mutability of URL content does make the long-term value of some SO questions problematic.

Or... you can post on meta (as you have done)... and the powers that be override the reviewers.

Comment: No one can override the reviewers.  Once the decision has been made it is finished.  And the OP to this question can edit the post himself without review.  We don't need a meta post every single time someone feels there was a wrongly reviewed edit, especially when that person can do something about it.