# If a review was approved by all but rejected by you, and you believe it should have been rejected

Tags: discussion, review-queues

If a review was approved by all, but rejected by you, and you believe it should have been rejected:

1. Do you flag the question for moderator attention "hey, people approved something wrong!"
2. Do you revert the edit with your privileges?
3. Do you create a new account and submit a revert edit for reverse-review by new peers?
4. Do you leave it like that: a review is a democratic process, and sometimes you lose.
5. Do you ask about it on Meta?
6. Do you ask about it on chat?

Note: no real case here, just a hypothetical question

Comment: I would go with 4

Comment: Same here. All 4.

Comment: I just found this related question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332552/bad-suggested-edit-approved-by-reviewers

Comment: You should have selected "reject and edit" option...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov oh good point! Will do next time.

Comment: The accepted answer, below sounds right on the money.

Comment: Almost the same question, just regarding dealing with bad rejections instead of bad accepts: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283172/1709587. The view I express in my answer there roughly applies here.

Comment: There are so many robo-reviewers out there approving without paying attention. If you are trully confident, reject and move on. Just flag for moderator if you see a pattern in one of the users of constantly approving trash.

Comment: @user000001 That's a bit categorical. Lots of times, even 3 reviewers at once are wrong, sometimes blatantly so.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It really depends on your level of expertise and the expertise of the other reviewers.

How confident are you that a mistake was made?

If you click through to the profiles of the other reviewers, do they have score and badges in tags relevant to the edit?  Do they have absurdly high acceptance rates, or does their history show they reject edits when they come across inappropriate ones?

- If the other reviewers are experts with a history of actually having rejected edits that deserve it, let it pass, you were wrong.
- If the other reviewers' history shows that they don't know what they are doing, or accept everything in a misguided sense of being nice to new users, and you took an extra look and are still sure the edit is wrong, then rollback and a moderator flag is appropriate.
- If you can't tell, then you may ask on Meta to get more expert eyes on the proposed edit.

You may also want to look at other edits suggested by the same user to see whether there is a pattern of making useless or wrong changes to try to gain reputation.

Comment: I put the long effort at looking at the other reviewers histories, and found one that was over-accepting suggested edits. I've just raised a moderator flag for it.

Comment: *"...are still sure the edit is wrong, then rollback..."* and if possible, [please also clearly mention the reason for the rollback](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41953).

Comment: The reputation or the number of badges of the other reviewers is a poor indication. Instead check their accept/reject ratio. If it is somewhere around 80/20 or higher, they are robo-reviewers.

Comment: @Pang They should really make that feature more obvious...

Comment: @Lundin how do you view accept/reject ratio?

Comment: @DForck42 You have to open up the specific review at a point when you yourself cannot cast a vote on it (either because the review is settled or because you are about to do the review). For example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14771389), click on "more". "Lundin has approved 1829 edit suggestions and rejected 2066 edit suggestions and improved 206 edit suggestions." So this guy is perhaps a bit pedantic, but definitely not a robo-reviewer.

Comment: @Lundin: I don't think you're saying anything different than what I already wrote in this answer, except that you're giving a number for "absurdly high acceptance rate".

Comment: what if changes was only remove few white space which is not making post useful then?

Comment: This is bad. Facts matter, not what people think or how often people were right.  You ignore that several people can be wrong. They collectively might not know better. Probability of them being wrong is irrelevant as long as someone can point out the fact that they indeed are wrong.

Comment: @z0rberg: That's why I started with "How confident are you that a mistake was made?"

Comment: Confidence should be irrelevant, because it's a gradient influenced by anxiety. When there's a suspicion that something is wrong, the correct course of action is finding proof and presenting it. Telling people to rely on their "confidence" will lead too many people into thoughts like "well, i'm not entirely sure so whatever", or "well, i'm sure i'm correct, but i don't want to argue". Both are bad, because they stop caring instead of looking it up and presenting it. People should be encouraged and motivated to double-check.

Comment: @z0rberg: here are some facts you're ignoring: not all proofs are correct. An astonishing number of people on this site "know" things that are wrong. If they don't sit up and take notice that experts disagree with them, they'll be stuck on false facts forever

Comment: So you support what I'm saying? As in: "don't blindly believe experts. check things if you think they're wrong." Your comment is confusing.

Comment: @z0rberg's who the heck is saying that we should "blindly believe experts"? If I know nothing of Java, and Jon Skeet tells me that my program is liable of memory leaking, you think I should dismiss it and not fix that problem?

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, we favor technical accuracy over everything else. That means that if you have domain knowledge about the topic, you can make an informed review of the changes, either by rollbacking or applying the edit. This would [prevent bad edits from being approved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338914/792066), while [allowing good edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339750/792066) [that improves the quality of the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338986/792066) to be applied.

Comment: While this is a nice statement of the ideal concept behind the review process, it does not actually answer the question. The question is asking for a course of action, or specifically if there should be no action.

Comment: @Makyen what? It says clearly: if you have domain knowledge about the topic, you can make an informed review of the changes. If OP knows that the edit is a improvement, he should apply it; if OP knows that the edit is detrimental, he should reject if; and if he doesn't know, he should abstain.

Comment: The question is not asking what to do *in the review queue*. It is asking what to do *after rejecting the edit in the review queue*, when you firmly believe the edit should have been rejected, but the the edit was ultimately approved.

Comment: @Makyen who is saying that you only review on the review queues? The main point is to make the most sensible action from a technical point of view. The edit was approved and you know it's technically detrimental, roll back; the edit was approved and you don't know if it's technically detrimental, you should allow others to decide.

Comment: This is a bit misleading, because while we strive for technical accuracy in edits of _answers_, we don't necessarily do that in edits of _questions_. An edit which fixes what seems like an obvious mistake, could be removing the actual source of the problem, so that neither the question nor any posted answers make any sense any longer. Overall, it is better if edits do not meddle with the technical contents of questions/answers. With the exception of tag wikis, you really don't need any technical expertise for suggested edit reviews. Close votes on the other hand, may need such expertise.

Comment: @Lundin what? "The rule is not to modify code in questions, **unless it is impossible that the edit can accidentally fix the problem.**" and for that you need to know what you are doing, or "have domain knowledge about the topic". It's not misleading. You are an expert, and we trust you know you are doing.

Comment: "You are an expert, and we trust you know you are doing." This trust is misplaced. Experts can be wrong and their past does not positively influence the probability of them being correct again and again and again. This is a rather dangerous way of thinking, because it grants people superiority over others based only on what they claim to be correct. This ends in *belief*, where people not question what "authority" claims to be the "truth".

Comment: @z0rberg's between a doctor and the old lady that lives on the street, to which you trust your health? Experts are less likely to be wrong, for that we call them "experts", they have "expertise".

Answer (score 3):

If you believe that the review was incorrect or if you simply don't understand why something was accepted/rejected, it is always a good idea to post a support request on meta with a link to the specific review.

Either the review was correct and then you can learn why from others, which will make you a better reviewer.

Or the review was incorrect, in which case someone with direct edit previligies can rollback/fix the post. Plus it may draw some moderator attention to potential robo-reviewers.

Although, if you find out that somebody is repeatedly robo-reviewing, it is better to flag a post with an edit that they incorrectly accepted and let the diamond mods deal with it.

Comment: "correct" for whom? Meta seems to support ["steamroll domain experts and throw out legitimate content"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338986/why-was-my-clarification-of-the-answerers-code-rejected?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment418846_338994) which is a scary train of thought.

Comment: @Braiam It entirely depends on which review queue we are talking about. Suggested edits and very low quality can usually be done without any domain knowledge at all. As for the linked question, it was rather about "steamroll people who think SO is Wikipedia". Questions/answers belong to the poster and shouldn't be wildly edited by others, no matter their intentions.

Comment: "Suggested edits ... can usually be done without any domain knowledge at all" [citation needed]!

Comment: @Braiam Speaking from experience, as I've apparently done over 4000 suggested edit reviews and who knows how many low-quality ones.

Comment: Well, how about these edits? https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10742414 https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14756615 and http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14318961 What would be your action and why?

Comment: @Braiam: Probably 70% of edits can be reviewed without domain knowledge.  Another 20% can be skipped without domain knowledge.  The problem is the remaining 10%, which require domain knowledge to see that the issue is actually a matter of technical expertise, and non-experts will review wrongly.  For this reason, it's good for non-experts to hit that skip button even if they think they could have done the review.

Comment: @BenVoigt actually, even for formatting/grammar you need domain knowledge: "is this correctly formating", "it this sentence correctly written", "doesn't misuse the backticks, bold and emphasis", "do the link that is being added authoritative", etc. That's why I barely would approve/reject an edit, most of the time I'm ill equipped to do a sensible review of the post.

Comment: @Braiam Regarding your second example, I have no idea what's going on there, except there's clearly a full-blown edit war going on, vandalizing the post to oblivion. See the radical edit done at Mar 9 '16 at 3:16. Why that edit was done, I have no idea, but it seems like vandalism to me. The best course of action from the start was clearly not to edit anything. Someone with domain knowledge will have to salvage that answer back to a point before the vandalism started. Overall, this post definitely proves my point of why edits changing the technical content of a post should be rejected.

Comment: What edit war? None of them had "edit wars".

Comment: @Braiam Just see the edit history.

Comment: @Lundin I saw the revision history, there's no evidence of "war". Unless you want to argue that because different users edited the same post is a war...

Comment: @Braiam http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2647888/revisions Last touch by the OP was May 4 '13. Someone added clutter at  Dec 3 '14, then rollback. Various minor edits follow, until the same "someone" for some reason deleted 90% of the post, including the original `===` part, with a reference to comments that no longer exist. Supposedly there was some heavy debate going on. Then 5 different users have been fighting over the `===` thing and the presence of the comment/link that you left there. Too bad the comments were deleted.

Comment: The correct approach would be to down vote the original for being incorrect (if it was), then posting a new, correct answer instead.

Comment: What? That edit was inappropriate in first place and not for any reason you argue. It was a commentary on the post, not information. The information (on the comment or elsewhere) had to be added into the post organically. That's why we delete answers that are barely a link to elsewhere. And even then that isn't a war.